# Laravel Array Format

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array built from an eloquent query which looks like this:

```
[['ctry' => 'US', 'subs' => 10], ['ctry' => 'AU', 'subs' => 25], ....]
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
['US' => 10, 'AU' => 25, ...]
```

I have tried `array_map`, `call_user_func_array`, laravel's `flatten` without success. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting data from the model, you can use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$model = Model::pluck('subs', 'ctry')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be

```
<?php
$sample_array = [['ctry' => 'US', 'subs' => 10], ['ctry' => 'AU', 'subs' => 25]]; # more elements in the array
$result_array = [];
foreach ($sample_array as $key => $value) {
    array_push($result_array, [$value['ctry'] => $value['subs']]);
}
print_r($result_array);
```